# Editing of an existing object should be done in repository layer or in service?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

For example if I have a User that has debt. I want to change his debt. Should I do it in UserRepository or in service for example BuyingService by getting an object, editing it and saving it ?

Comment: We need more info about your setup. What regulates the debt? Is it a field in the `user` class? At first glance I'd say: retrieve the user from the repository and call some method from the user class that changes the debt.

Comment: yes, debt is a field in user class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should leave the responsibility of mutating an object to that same object and use the repository to retrieve this object.

Example situation:

```
class User {
 private int debt; // debt in cents
 private string name;

 // getters

 public void makePayment(int cents){
  debt -= cents;
 }
}

class UserRepository {
 public User GetUserByName(string name){
  // Get appropriate user from database
 }
}
```

Usage (Jack pays 10€):

```
userRepository.GetUserByName("Jack").makePayment(1000);
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example approach. There is not one set way in programming to achieve something, you could very well do this entirely different.

Comment: Business logic should really be in a service. Not in a model.

Comment: @Steve: I have dedicated a question on programmers.SE to this statement. Please feel free to join in and clarify your statement, I can imagine a comment box will not suffice and is rather annoying to use in the first place. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-accurate-is-business-logic-should-be-in-a-service-not-in-a-model